# Sum with irrational powers and binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

What is the value of:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} {\left(\left(-1\right)^{n-k}{n+1 \choose k+1}\left(\frac{\sqrt5}{1+\sqrt5}\left(3+\sqrt5\right)^k-\frac{\sqrt5}{1-\sqrt5}\left(3-\sqrt5\right)^k-\frac{5}{2}\right)\right)}?$$
I am stuck because of the binomial coefficient there, because without it the sum would just be a bunch of geometric series.

Comment: Well, what do you know about the binomial expansion theorem?

Comment: I know that $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {\left({n\choose k}a^k b^{n-k}\right)}$, if that's what you mean

Comment: Using that, you can then derive the closed form of your sum as martycohen has laid out for you.

Comment: Ah! I have worked it out now on my own

Comment: Wonderful!  And welcome to the site :D

Comment: Thanks! :D
And as I commented below, the answer reduces very neatly and in simplest form appears to be $\frac{5}{4}F_{3n}$. (!)

Comment: Oh, wow, much nicer than anything I was expecting XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} {\left(\left(-1\right)^{n-k}{n+1 \choose k+1}\left(\frac{\sqrt5}{1+\sqrt5}\left(3+\sqrt5\right)^k-\frac{\sqrt5}{1-\sqrt5}\left(3-\sqrt5\right)^k-\frac{5}{2}\right)\right)}?
$

Here's a start.
I'm feeling too tired right now
to do more.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n} {n+1 \choose k+1} x^k
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} {n+1 \choose k} x^{k-1}\\
&=\frac1{x}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} {n+1 \choose k} x^{k}\\
&=\frac1{x}\left(-1-(n+1)x+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+1 \choose k} x^{k}\right)\\
&=\frac1{x}\left((1+x)^{n+1}-1-(n+1)x\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Note that
$(3-\sqrt{5})(3+\sqrt{5})
=4
$.

If $x = -(3+\sqrt{5})$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n} {n+1 \choose k+1}(-1)^k (3+\sqrt{5})^k
&=\frac1{-(3+\sqrt{5})}\left((1-(3+\sqrt{5}))^{n+1}-1+(n+1)(3+\sqrt{5})\right)\\
&=\frac{-(3-\sqrt{5})}{4}\left((-1)^{n+1}(2+\sqrt{5})^{n+1}-1+(n+1)(3+\sqrt{5})\right)\\
\end{array}
$

That's all.

Comment: In simplest form, the answer appears to be $\frac{5}{4}F_{3n}$. How neat. :)